# How to display a maximum number of characters on html page

Tags: html

Say I have the following code

```
<h1>I like watermelon and I cannot lie, and stuff and things</h1>
```

however, on the html page I want to maximize the number of character displayed.  In other words, I want the html page to only display something like:

I like watermelon and ...

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
h1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 75px; //Depends how much you want to show.
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this is not really what I want.